# Visual Studio Project Backup

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Right now I am saving my all visual studio projects in C drive.

Now I want to keep copy of that all projects in some other drive, so if my C drive get crashed then also I can access all projects.

So what is best way for that.

If I just make zip of current projects from C drive and paste it in another drive.

And when needed I extract it, then will it work OR any error will come.

Thanks for help in Advance.

Comment: Ideally you should be using a version control like TFS. Because of some reasons if you can't use, restoring from zip will work without any issue.

Comment: Please read [ask]. You should research your problem before asking a new question. The de facto answer to _"How do I back up my source code?"_ is _"Use version control such as Git or TFS and store that off-premise"_. As for _"[when] I extract [my zipped code], then will it work OR any error will come"_ - try it, preferably on a different machine.

Answer (score 7):

> If I just make zip of current projects from C drive and paste it in another drive.

Well you could do that but it's rather tedius; error-prone and rather brute-force.  It's difficult to maintain history.

A better choice is to use some form of *source control* (SC) / *software configuration management* (SCM).  SC is a tool for maintaining a code repository.  It works by associating metadata about every source file and any changes you make.

e.g.

- [*Git*](https://git-scm.com/download/win)
- [*Subversion*](https://tortoisesvn.net/)
- [*Microsoft TFS*](https://www.visualstudio.com/tfs/)
- [*Perforce*](https://www.perforce.com/)
- [*IBM/Rational ClearCase*](https://www.ibm.com/au-en/marketplace/rational-clearcase)
- *Microsoft SourceSafe* (ewww, retried thankfully)

Source control not only keeps a copy somewhere else (ideally a different computer) but it also allows you to

- **keep track** of what changed
- **rollback** a change
- **share** with your friends or colleges
- **integrates** nicely with your IDE of choice (VS) or command-line

But in this day and age there are plenty of **free** cloud-based solutions that offer you more than just acting as a code repository such as stats; wikis; bug tracking; and spiffy charts.  Check out:

- [*Microsoft Visual Studio Team Services* (VSTS)](https://www.visualstudio.com/vso/)
- [*Github*](https://github.com/)
- [*Atlassian Bitbucket*](https://bitbucket.org/)

### Summary

Irrespective of whether you perform manual folder copies or use source control; both will lead to a copy of your code.  However only the latter introduces workflows and due-diligence (via SCM) so that as you code you are unlikely to lose information due to the procedures and safeguards in place.

### A word on file backup

If for some absolute reason you decide not to proceed with SC but rather stick with **plain-old-file-backup** then at least follow the fine wisdom of [Scott Hanselman (MSFT)](https://www.hanselman.com/) where he talks about file backup best practices:

> I've got a number of backups because I practice the Backup Rule of Three.
>
> - **3 copies of anything you care about** - Two isn't enough if it's important.
> - **2 different formats** - Example: Dropbox+DVDs or Hard Drive+Memory Stick or CD+Crash Plan, or more
> - **1 off-site backup** - If the house burns down, how will you get your memories back?

...using apps like *CrashPlan*.

Scott will most likely agree that his plan **wasn't intended for source code** but at least you have 3 backups of **files** as he recommends.

### See Also

- Hanselman, S, [*"Is your stuff backed up? Recovering from a hardware failure"*](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/IsYourStuffBackedUpRecoveringFromAHardwareFailure.aspx)

Comment: _"ewww, retried thankfully"_ If you meant to say "retired", I'd wholeheartedly agree :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/). You can add code to source control (I would use Git if I were you) and manage your projects there for free.

Having your code in a source control system has many benefits, like having history of each commit.

Next to that, VSTS has lots of opions like [Continuous Integration / Continuous Deployment](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/continuous-integration/), [Testing](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/testing-tools/), project management support like making your project an [Agile](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/agile-tools/) project.

Answer (score 0):

What will you do if hard drive crash?

Code Management is a practice and there are many tools to help you to manage your code. Try [GitHub](https://github.com) or [bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org)

Moreover you can also zip the code and save on external disks but check how much risk is involved with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a .zip archive to back up your work, but this is slightly laborious and will likely include a number of files you do not need to get up and running again (for example the build output, nuget packages folders, etc.) which will bloat your archives.

A better option would be to use a Version Control System of some kind, which will allow you to back up those parts of the project/solution that actually need to be backed up while ignoring the parts that can be rebuilt from the code. A good walk through of what and why can be found in [Version Control By Example](http://ericsink.com/vcbe/html/index.html), which also includes comparisons about different types of VCS as well as how to perform many of the usual tasks.

There are various free options out there, based on a number of different providers. As some examples, I've used the following services, and all of them will give you a free account, and some will also give you private repositories (so that random members of the public can't see your work if that's what you want):

- [GitHub](http://github.com) - unlimited public repositories, uses Git.
- [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org) - unlimited private repositories, uses Git or Mercurial
- [Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/vso/) - unlimited private repositories, uses Git or TFS

Using an online provider will give you the added benefit of the backups being on a third party - so if your disk fails you'll still have a backup, as well as the other benefits a VCS will provide (the ability to rollback to a specific point in time, annotations about changes, etc.).